# Redact XML using XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xml-parsing, transform

Wondering if anyone can help with an XSLT issue I am facing.

I am trying to create an xslt script which will take take as input an xml document and change the values of several fields to "xxxx" I have managed to get this part working however I would now only like this to run if one field in the input xml is of a specific value (e.g. if username is jbond)

I like to have this condition within my XSLT if possible however I am having difficulty.

My current XML, XSLT, Output and expected outputs are as follows

XML:

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?>
        <rootDoc>
        <user>test</user>
        <tel>12345</tel>
        <zip>abcd</zip>
</rootDoc>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:if test="user = 'test'">
      <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tel/text()">XXXX</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="zip/text()">XXXX</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootDoc/>
```

Expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?><rootDoc>
   <user>test</user>
   <tel>XXXX</tel>
   <zip>XXXX</zip>
</rootDoc>
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting the test into the identity transformation template does not make much sense, if you want to perform certain changes when a condition holds then the templates

```
<xsl:template match="tel/text()">XXXX</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="zip/text()">XXXX</xsl:template>
```

should be changed to

```
<xsl:template match="rootDoc[user = 'test']/tel/text()">XXXX</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="rootDoc[user = 'test']/zip/text()">XXXX</xsl:template>
```

which could be joined into

```
<xsl:template match="rootDoc[user = 'test']/tel/text() | rootDoc[user = 'test']/zip/text()">XXXX</xsl:template>
```

With a single condition, assuming it is the rootNode, you can use

```
<xsl:template match="/rootNode[not(user = 'test')]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

then the other cases are handled by the identity transformation and the specialized templates.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Would you know if it's possible to have a more generic solution which will only run the condition once rather than for each node. in the final document there are several fields we wish to sanitize and for this reason we are trying to reduce the number of repetitive conditions

Comment: If you know you don't want to change anything in case the condition does not hold then you can use a template for the root element which simply copies everything instead of applying templates.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave the identity transform alone, but add specific matches, XSLT will automagically find the closest match. You can customize the select="" or add more templates as necessary. hth

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tel"><tel>XXXX</tel></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="zip"><zip>XXXX</zip></xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rootDoc>
        <user>test</user>
        <tel xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">XXXX</tel>
        <zip xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">XXXX</zip>
</rootDoc>